# How to concatenate vectors of different lengths without recycling and without using a loop?

Tags: r

Let's say I  have two vectors of different lengths:

```
v1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
v2 <- c("F", "G", "H")
```

I want to concatenate these two vectors.  But I don't want to recycle the short vector.  I just want NAs for the missing elements.  So I want this:

```
[1] "A-F"  "B-G"  "C-H"  "D-NA" "E-NA"
```

If I use paste, the short vector gets recycled:

```
paste(v1, v2, sep = "-")
# [1] "A-F" "B-G" "C-H" "D-F" "E-G"
```

I could do it easily with a loop:

```
v3 <- c()
for (i in seq_along(v1)) {
 v3[i] <- paste(v1[i], v2[i], sep = "-")  
}

v3
# [1] "A-F"  "B-G"  "C-H"  "D-NA" "E-NA"
```

But if anyone on StackOverflow discovered I was extending a vector dynamically inside a loop, they would have a conniption.

So, how can I concatenate two vectors of different lengths without recycling and without using a loop?

Comment: Store the vectors in a list (especially if you have many of them) (`l = list(v1, v2)`). Index all vectors with the maximum length and paste them together (`do.call(paste, lapply(l, function(x) x[seq_len(max(lengths(l)))]))`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the length of the longest vector and set the length of each vector to that, then concatenate.

```r
v1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
v2 <- c("F", "G", "H")

n <- max(length(v1), length(v2))

length(v1) <- n
length(v2) <- n

paste(v1, v2, sep = "-")
#> [1] "A-F"  "B-G"  "C-H"  "D-NA" "E-NA"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

We could create a list. Add `NA`'s to make equal length. then `paste` the elements of the list:

```
my_list <- list(v1, v2)
my_list1 <- lapply(my_list, `length<-`, max(lengths(my_list)))
paste(my_list1[[1]], my_list1[[2]], sep="-")
```

```
[1] "A-F"  "B-G"  "C-H"  "D-NA" "E-NA"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also use

```
 do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(stringi::stri_list2matrix(list(v1, v2))), sep="-"))
[1] "A-F"  "B-G"  "C-H"  "D-NA" "E-NA"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could complete the shorter vector with `"NA"`

```
v1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
v2 <- c("F", "G", "H")

n_v1 <- length(v1)
n_v2 <- length(v2)

if(n_v1 > n_v2){
  paste(v1,c(v2,rep("NA",(n_v1-n_v2))),sep = "-")
  }

[1] "A-F"  "B-G"  "C-H"  "D-NA" "E-NA"
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Somehow this doesn't satisfy me, however.  I'll accept this if no one comes up with anything better.